# php - Connect to blockchain.info rpc

Tags: php, bitcoin, blockchain

1 hour ago i was finish with my dice-betting site like bitsler.com, hosted everything but the only problem i have is now that i can't connect to blockchain.info with rpc. What to fix here:

```
include 'driver_test.php'; # here is jsonRPCClient class in
$w_user = "WALLET-ID";
$w_pass = "PASSWORD";
$w_host = "rpc.blockchain.info";
$w_port = "443";
$test=new  jsonRPCClient('http://'.$_GET['w_user'].':'.$_GET['w_pass'].'@'.$_GET['w_host'].':'.$_GET['w_port'].'/');
@$test_call=$test->getbalance();

echo json_encode(array('result'=>$test_call));
```

So what to do to fix it?
Regards, Christian

Comment: Can you remove `@` symbol to not suppress errors? Then post your error message here and we can help.

Comment: You are trying to use the HTTP protocol on port 443.. Change the `jsonRPCClient` call to start with `https`?

Comment: I tried it but it doesnt work either